# How to implement Android Fragments like functionality in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fragment

I am building an app for Android and iOS both using React Native. I want to implement android Fragments like functionality in which multiple screens will switch on same screen. I checked about React.Fragment but don't know is this correct or not. Please help. Suggest something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are also support available in React, we can access it as below:

```
<React.Fragment>
    {
      /*
        Sub Components
      */
    }  
</React.Fragment>
```

check out the official doc for more details.

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html